# Why doesn't my NamedPipeServerStream wait?

Tags: c#, named-pipes, iasyncresult, waithandle

I'm working with a NamedPipeServerStream to communicate between two processes.  Here is the code where I initialize and connect the pipe:

```
void Foo(IHasData objectProvider)
{
    Stream stream = objectProvider.GetData();
    if (stream.Length > 0)
    {
        using (NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("VisualizerPipe", PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous))
        {
            string currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            string uiFileName = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "VisualizerUIApplication.exe");
            Process.Start(uiFileName);
            if(pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(PipeConnected, this).AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(5000))
            {
                while (stream.CanRead)
                {
                    pipeServer.WriteByte((byte)stream.ReadByte());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new TimeoutException("Pipe connection to UI process timed out.");
            }
        }
    }
}

private void PipeConnected(IAsyncResult e)
{
}
```

But it never seems to wait.  I constantly get the following exception:

**System.InvalidOperationException: Pipe hasn't been connected yet.
   at System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.CheckWriteOperations()
   at System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.WriteByte(Byte value)
   at PeachesObjectVisualizer.Visualizer.Show(IDialogVisualizerService windowService, IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider)**

I would think that after the wait returns everything should be ready to go.

If I use pipeServer.WaitForConnection() everything works fine, but hanging the application if the pipe doesn't connect is not an option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call [EndWaitForConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.endwaitforconnection(v=VS.90).aspx).

```
var asyncResult = pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(PipeConnected, this);

if (asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(5000))
{
    pipeServer.EndWaitForConnection(asyncResult);

    // ...
}
```

See: [IAsyncResult design pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx).

Comment: I tried this approach and now it waits for about 10 seconds before connecting, but when I don't use BeginWait it connects instantly.  According to MSDN AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(5000) blocks until signaled but that is apparently not the case.

Comment: Sorry, my copy code was wrong and was causing it to hang for a little while.  I fixed the code and now this works.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mind sharing what you did to fix it? I have the same problem.